# Py2app prevents wxpython opening second wx.Frame

Tags: python, wxpython, py2app

I have a python script which process's Quicktime files, while this process can take quite a long time to execute and complete, I have a second window opening (which opens and stays on top of everything else saying 'Please Wait', BusyWindow Class), then closes when finished. This all works fine while in python script form, but when creating a Py2app, which bundles everything up including wxpython, the second window fails to open. While still open if I run it again the second window now opens. I have seen another post about this issue, but no fixes, anyone have any suggestions please?

```
import wx
import os
import os.path
import inspect
import csv
import subprocess
import sys
import shutil
import re
import urllib2
import threading
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class ScrolledWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(510, 370), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | 
                                                wx.RESIZE_BOX | 
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        self.tabbed = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=(wx.NB_TOP))

        run_params = {}
        run_params["dropList1"] = ['HD 1920x1080', 'PAL 4x3', 'PAL 16x9', 'NTSC 4x3', 'NTSC 16x9']
        run_params["dropList2"] = ['Progressive', 'Interlaced']
        run_params["running"] = False
        run_params["1stRun"] = True

        self.CreateStatusBar()
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu = wx.Menu()
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        self.filePrep = PrepFile(self.tabbed, run_params)

        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.filePrep, "File Prep")

class PrepFile(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, run_params):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.run_params = run_params
        self.fieldChoice = 'Progressive'
        self.formatOption = 'HD 1920x1080'

        outputOption = '''Format'''
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, outputOption, (33, 22), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)


        self.choice1 = wx.Choice(self, pos=(35, 40), choices=self.run_params["dropList1"])
        self.choice1.SetSelection(0)
        self.choice1.SetFocus()
        self.choice1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.selectOption)

        fieldSetText = '''Fields'''
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, fieldSetText, (33, 82), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        self.choice2 = wx.Choice(self, pos=(35, 100), choices=self.run_params["dropList2"])
        self.choice2.SetSelection(0)
        self.choice2.SetFocus()
        self.choice2.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, self.fieldSet)

        self.buttonClose = wx.Button(self, -1, "Quit", pos=(195, 250))
        self.buttonClose.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)

        greyBox = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, '', pos=(20, 15), size=(235, 130))

        outputtxt3 = '''Drag and Drop Quicktimes'''
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, outputtxt3, pos=(35, 170), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        self.drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.SetDropTarget(self.drop_target)
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(38, 190), size=(200, 25))
        self.buttonSubmit = wx.Button(self, -1, "Submit", pos=(250,190))
        self.buttonSubmit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.submit)

    def EvtRadioBox(self, event):
        self.mode = (event.GetString())

    def selectOption(self, e):
        self.formatOption = self.choice1.GetStringSelection()

    def fieldSet(self, e):
        self.fieldChoice = self.choice2.GetStringSelection()

    def setSubmissionDrop(self, dropFiles):
        """Called by the FileDropTarget when files are dropped"""
        self.tc_files.SetValue(','.join(dropFiles))
        self.selectedFiles = dropFiles
        print self.selectedFiles

    def submit(self, edit):
        self.run_params["running"] = True
        busy = BusyWindow(None, self.run_params)
        for item in self.selectedFiles:
            if os.path.isdir(item):
                print "It is a folder!"
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(item):
                    for file1 in files:
                        if file1.endswith(".mov"):
                            currentFile = os.path.join(root, file1)
                            self.jesFile(currentFile)
            else:
                if item.endswith(".mov"):
                    self.jesFile(item)
        busy.Close()

    def OnClose(self, e):
        CloseApp()

    def jesFile(self, currentFile):
        if self.fieldChoice == "Interlaced":
            if self.formatOption == 'HD 1920x1080':
                self.preset = 'HD 1080i'
            elif self.formatOption == 'PAL 4x3':
                self.preset = 'PAL 4x3i'
            elif self.formatOption == 'PAL 16x9':
                self.preset = 'PAL 16x9i'
            elif self.formatOption == 'NTSC 4x3':
                self.preset = 'NTSC 4x3i'
            elif self.formatOption == 'NTSC 16x9':
                self.preset = 'NTSC 16x9i'
        else:
            if self.formatOption == 'HD 1920x1080':
                self.preset = 'HD 1080p'
            elif self.formatOption == 'PAL 4x3':
                self.preset = 'PAL 4x3p'
            elif self.formatOption == 'PAL 16x9':
                self.preset = 'PAL 16x9p'
            elif self.formatOption == 'NTSC 4x3':
                self.preset = 'NTSC 4x3p'
            elif self.formatOption == 'NTSC 16x9':
                self.preset = 'NTSC 16x9p'

        # Apply JES settings
        jesCommand = './JES/JES\ Extensifier.app/Contents/MacOS/JES\ Extensifier   -p   ' + '"' + self.preset + '"' + '   ' + '"' + currentFile + '"'
        print jesCommand
        self.process1 = Popen(jesCommand, shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
        self.assignAudio(currentFile)

class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        self.window.setSubmissionDrop(filenames)

class CloseApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(e):
        sys.exit(0)

class BusyWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, run_params):
        self.run_params = run_params
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, '', size=(350,80), style=wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "                    Processing files. Please wait. \n                     DON'T TOUCH ANYTHING!")
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
ScrolledWindow(None, -1, 'iTunes Quicktime File Prep')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: To confirm, on the first run of your program the secondary window does _not_ display, but on subsequent runs of your program it _does_?

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't some problem in the for loop that is causing it to go almost immediately to the `busy.Close()`? Or perhaps some exception that is being raised so it bails out and never calls `Close()` (in the case that appears to be working.)  Either way you should read about better ways to handle long running tasks without blocking the GUI.  http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking_Gui
http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter

Comment: I am absolutely sure there is no problem with the loop, or exception, as it runs perfect in IDLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrestled with this problem for quite a while this evening. What seems to have worked was setting the `argv_emulation` option in py2app to `False`.

When enabled, `argv_emulation` captures certain AppleEvents, which get converted into strings and stuffed into sys.argv. When used with applications using GUI toolkits, I suspect this swallows some AppleEvents that wxPython is expecting to receive.

Comment: This fixed my issue: my wxPython GUIs wouldn't pop up when I clicked on the icon.  I had to double click the icon, _then_ either click it again or click on the icon in the dock.  Now it works correctly the first time.  Thanks!